# Will Gtk3 applications run in MATE?

Tags: gtk3, mate

MATE, the Gnome 2 fork is still using Gtk3, although I think they have plans to migrate to Gtk3 in the future. Currently, is it possible to run Gtk3 applications in MATE?

Answer (score 3):

MATE was forked on purpose to stay with Gtk2, for reasons of performance and maintainability; a desktop with similar panel arrangements but using Gtk3 is Cinnamon.
See [Why was MATE created](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=100773&p=576203) on the Linux Mint forums.

When running Gtk3 applications in MATE you'll notice they look different, unless you are using a theme that supports both Gtk2 and Gtk3, with sensibly a similar look. You'll have to select the theme in both Preferences/Aspect applet for Gtk2 and gnome-tweak-tool for Gtk3.

Comment: so just to confirm, gtk3 applications can still be used inside MATE, and will not conflict with anything?

Comment: lol I just realised the linked thread was started by me xD

Comment: lol, next time I'll double check that! As of now, I'm having issues with some applets' transparencies on Trusty Tahr, and certain bugs seem to come back, like indicator applet complete not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

MATE can still run with GTK3 applications, but make sure that the theme have GTK3 theme support. To change the theme that supports both GTK2 and GTK3, go to System > Preferences > Appearance. Then select the GTK theme you want to use from the Themes tab.